# Any good book about ayurveda?

Tags: food, resource, book-recommendation, ayurveda, health

I just discovered some benefits of ayurveda but I do not know almost anything about this; and in order to live better I would like to arrange my routine (food, time, habits, etc.) as it is prescribed for my main dosha.

To accomplish this I would appreciate it if you cold recommend me any extensive good book to buy in Amazon about this beautiful topic.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! Note that resource or book recommendation is fine but shoping recommendation is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Ayurveda Encyclopedia by Swami Sadashiva tirtha can be used as reference. But even good book for beginners.

Comment: ayurvedic although an ancient Indian cultural tradition, is not part of the Hindu religion.

Answer (score 5):

BhAvaprakAsh (by BhAva Mishra) is a good (probably the best) book on the subject.

It can be bought [here](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/bhava-prakasha-of-jivanath-jha-NZA406/) (Original Sanskrit+Hindi translation). Or from [here](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/bhavaprakasa-of-bhavamisra-two-volumes-NAD557/) (Original Sanskrit+English translation). Plenty of options to choose from [here.](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/find.php?pagecount=1&searchmodifier=allwords&limitfields=all&subcatsearch=all&materialsearch=all&minprice=0&maxprice=1000000&archives=0&searchsorttype=testcode%7Cdesc&table=book&searchval=bhavaprakash&search_submit=GO)

About the book:

> Bhava Prakash (14th century) This is the most important text, written
>   by Bhava-Mishra on the information of plants and herbs, which are
>   widely used in Ayurvedic formulations.

Source- [This page](http://www.sandu.in/bhavprakasha.html).

I myself do not have the book, but i have other books that cite this book often. and, that's how i got aware of it's existence.

Comment: charakasamhita too... isn't?

Comment: Yes of course, Charak and Susruta are scriptures, what i gave is a book but not scripture (Shastra) @Fiercelord I thought Op is looking a book.

Comment: sorry, i misundestood it. ;)

Comment: @Fiercelord No it can be that i have misunderstood..:) but this book is great book on the subject..

Comment: Yes for dooing ayurveda remedies it is good to go through these book written by some grear scholar and acharyas it is like a day to day remedial quide type. :)